# Android in-app products not appearing in app

Tags: android, in-app-billing, google-play-console

I have created an app with in-app products. I've added the licensing key and billing permission in my app and created in-app products in the developer console. And I'm using Android In-App Billing v3 Library to handle all purchases operations

The products in the play console are active and I've published the app and I can now see it and download it in the Google Play Store.

The problem is I can't get the in-app products when I try to list any products! They're not showing up in the Play Store, and I get the error: BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_BILLING_UNAVAILABLE and error value :3

My google play app is updated and is connected with Gmail account

Is there any restrictions for in-app products to show up based on location (I live in Palestine, Gaza) or the problem is pure technical ?? Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several days of searching, I figured out that Palestine in not supported by google play, so I did the following to overcome this issue:

1. I downloaded a VPN app on my mobile
2. I have cleared the cash and data of my google play (this is from settings/apps/ google play/storage)
3. I selected a European country and turned the VPN on
4. When restarting google play app, in the profile, choose the country that you have previously selected in the VPN app
5. Now Google play app runs from this selected country
6. When I have run my app, everything works fine and all errors disappeared